# To construct a pyramid with uses of alphabets. Would you propose any better solution?

Tags: c

Expected Input:
Enter the number of rows: 5

Expected Output:

```
        A
      A B A 
    A B C B A
  A B C D C B A
A B C D E D C B A
```

I have solved this problem in this way->

```
//Write a program to build a pyramid with uses of alphabets
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void){

//Put variables here
int space,num_of_rows,p=1,t=0;
char alphabet[100]={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

printf("Enter the number of rows : ");
//Getting the input from the user
scanf("%d",&num_of_rows);

//Handling total row issues
for(int i=0; i<num_of_rows; i++){


//Handling space issues
for(space=0; space<num_of_rows-i; space++)
    printf(" ");

    //Handling alphabets
    for(int j=1; j<=p; j++){

            //To construct the first row and first position of each of the row as A
            if(i==0 || j==1){

                    alphabet[t]='A';

            }
            //To construct the last position of each of the row as A
            else if(j==p){

                    alphabet[t]='A';


            }
            //Handling the middle position issues
            else if(i+1>=j){

                    alphabet[t]++;

                }

            else{
                    alphabet[t]--;


                }
            printf("%c",alphabet[t]);



    }
    printf("\n");
    p+=2;

   }
 }
```

Now what I want to accomplish from you: How can I simplify my solution?. Will I face any problem for some conditions? Is it possible to solve this problem without using an array? Then what will be the strategy?. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you wish to improve the algorithm, then Google "Pascal's Triangle". (You just print letters instead of digits.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### General Observations

The code works as long as the user puts in correct limited values.

The indentation is a little off.

You can decrease the vertical spacing quite a bit, most of the blank lines aren't necessary.

### Answers

> Will I face any problem for some conditions?

If a user enters a negative number or a number greater than 100 this program will have problems with indexing. Always check user input for correctness and possible error conditions. The program will actually have problems if a user enters a number greater than 52 because there are only 26 letters in the alphabet.

> How can I simplify my solution?.

You could break the program up into functions, it's not quite necessary with a program this simple, but it is getting close. Two obviously separate functions that could be implemented right now are `get_and_validate_user_input()` and `print_pyramid()`. While functions might seem to make the program more complex and longer each function would be a simpler implementation and building block of the overall implementation.

> Is it possible to solve this problem without using an array? Then what will be the strategy?.

Yes. It would be possible to treat the numbers as a value in a range between 'A' and 'Z'.

### One Declaration Per Line

This line in the code could cause problems in maintenance in a larger program

```
int space,num_of_rows,p=1,t=0;
```

Break it up into 3 lines and always initialize variables in C.

```
int space = 0;
int num_of_rows = 0;
int p = 1;
int t = 0;
```